# Is this data representation here exact for One-Hot Encoding?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to encode the mushroom dataset here (https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/mushroom-classification) using One-Hot Encoding. Here is the code that I used (in Python) for the encoding:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
second_df = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore').fit_transform(new_df)
print(second_df)
```

The result for my code is in this image, and that makes me quite confusing: [Result for the encoding.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHkYX.png)

Is this result the right representation for my One-Hot Encoding? If not, what shall I do to fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

The output looks a bit unusual because [**`OneHotEncoder`**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) returns a [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) by default:

> *`OneHotEncoder(*, categories='auto', drop=None, sparse=True, dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>, handle_unknown='error')`*

Sparse output is interpreted as **`(row, col) non_zero_value`**, where all the unlisted coordinates are zero:

```
(0, 1)    1.0         # value 1.0 at row 0, col 1
(0, 7)    1.0         # value 1.0 at row 0, col 7
...
```

---

To get a dense array instead,

- either set `sparse=False`:

  ```py
  OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit_transform(new_df)
  ```
- or chain [**`toarray`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html):

  ```py
  OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(new_df).toarray()
  ```

Output:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 0.],
       ...,
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

Comment: Thank you! I will apply it to my code for now!

Comment: Also, what does the header like (0,2), (0,6) in the result mean? Since when I try to split the data (using train_test_split), both the training set and the test set have the same header like that, so I am worried that both of them are not separate from each other.

Comment: @HoangCuongNguyen In a sparse matrix, everything is 0 except at those coordinates. The purpose is to save space instead of storing a bunch of redundant zeros. Unless both sets have the exact same coordinates, it should be fine.